# I want to change the db server on application manifest file

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, visual-studio, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce (Windows) application that is connected to a SQL Server database. This db resides on a remote machine. Recently, I have migrated the database to a new machine. I want the application to point to this new machine. I try to change the IP of the machine on the WindowsApplication1.exe.config.deploy file but when I try to ri-install the program the following message is showing: Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all. Please, can you help me how can I perform the change of the machine in this case?

Thanks,
KLEDI

Answer (score 1):

In the case of modify your application file you must update manifest hash for this file and resign .application & .manifest files.

**How to update and resign?**

You can use Microsoft [Mage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mage-exe-manifest-generation-and-editing-tool) application. You need -Update and -Sign commands. Take a look on **Remarks** part, there is a lot of examples for this commands.

One of more is here:

```
mage -Update HelloWorld.deploy -AppManifest 1.0.0.0\application.manifest -AppCodeBase http://internalserver/HelloWorld.deploy
mage -Sign deploy.application -CertFile cert.pfx -Password <passwd>
```

Remember this order:

1. -Update command
2. -Sign  command

Pfx (certificate file) you can found in your executable project files list. If you missing (.pfx) just go to your executable file Visual Studio project and go to **Signing** tab. Click on **Create Test Certificate** and use it for sign.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sergey. Thanks for the reply. Please can you be more specific on how can I generate the .pfx file with Visual Studio? Currenlty, I am unable to generate it.

Comment: Hi Sergey. I will try to generate it. Thanks again.